# Тире в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

ПОДСКАЖИТЕ ЕЩЕ, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА.
Если в простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля речи тире ставится в зависимости от того, какое слово выделяется интонацией, то в остальных случаях по правилу: "Если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными и между главными членами предложения нет отрицательной частицы НЕ, вводного слова, сравнительного союза, обстоятельства или дополнения, то необходимо поставить тире." 
Например: "Москва - столица нашей родины", "Отец его - военный доктор, сосланный Николаем Первым..." В этих случаях нет исключений? Тире ставится всегда? 
 И такое предложение: "Человек, которого я видел вчера () главный врач". Здесь нужна запятая или тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таких предложениях тире носит характер логического определения и всегда ставится. В последнем случае запятая закрывает придаточное предложение, а тире ставится по правилу.

Answer (score 2):

В этой теме важно понять следующее:

1) при наличии слова-связки (ЭТО, ВОТ, ЭТО ЗНАЧИТ) между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым тире ставится всегда.

2) Во всех остальных случаях на постановку тире влияют определенные факторы, а именно: способ выражения подлежащего и сказуемого; наличие частиц, союзов, вводных слов; особые случаи (инверсия главных членов, фразеологические обороты, разговорный стиль и специальная литература), авторское тире.

3) Постановку тире следует проверить наличием паузы в устной речи.

ПРИМЕРЫ

(1)"Москва - столица нашей родины". Сущ. И.п. - сущ. И.п., частиц и союзов нет, стиль нейтральный, ставится тире. Это формальное решение по правилу. Проверяем интонацию: подлежащее выделено логическим ударением, затем следует пауза.

(2)"Отец его - военный доктор, сосланный Николаем Первым..." . Сравним: Мой отец военный доктор. В разговорном стиле паузы нет, тире не ставится. В приведенном примере тире ставится обязательно, что определяется наличием местоимения "его". Логическим ударением выделяется слово "отец", а пауза делается после местоимения. Но даже при отсутствии местоимения тире нужно поставить в связи распространенностью сказуемого. "Его отец - военный доктор..."

(3) "Человек, которого я видел вчера, - главный врач". Здесь постановке тире также способствует распространенность подлежащего.  Фактически пауза разделяет группу подлежащего и группу сказуемого.

Другие примеры:  Человек, равнодушный к родному языку, –  дикарь. Наш век (я не боюсь повториться) – век больших скоростей. Разработать названия знаков, как разработаны названия цветов, – дело будущего.